# UML DeploymentDiagram for docker

Tags: docker, deployment, containers, uml

I m trying to do a deployment diagram having docker, I understand that a `<<device node>>` is used to represent the physical device. The `<<execution environment>>` node represents the environment in which the software is running on.

As I will be representing docker containers as nodes, I'm confused how Images should be represented?

In my diagram I made a node representing a docker container and inside artifacts representing various images.
I wonder if this is the correct representation?

Comment: The correct keywords are «executionEnvironment» and «device»

Comment: Could you post the image of your diagram, please?

Answer (score 2):

The UML semantics rely primarily on nodes, which MAY be subdivided into `«device»` and `«executionEnvironment»`:

> Nodes may be further sub-typed as Devices and ExecutionEnvironments. Devices represent physical machine components. ExecutionEnvironments represent standard software systems that application components may require at execution time. Specific profiles might, for example, define stereotypes for ExecutionEnvironments such as «OS», «workflow engine», «database system», and «J2EE container».

In comparison, [Docker](https://www.docker.com/resources/what-container/) containers are defined :

> Containers are an abstraction **at the app layer** that packages code and dependencies together. **Multiple containers** can run on the same machine and share the OS kernel with other containers, each running as isolated processes in user space.

According to the (UML) book, it wouldn't be a device, since the physical layer is missing. But one could argue that virtual devices could be considered as a particular kind of devices. Nevertheless, Docker itself opposes container technology to virtual machines. This should lead us to consider it as execution environment. Even more, other container technologies are quoted as example for execution environments.

Since execution environments can be nested,  it would not be a problem to have an OS as a nested execution environment inside a docker execution environment.

A less ambiguous way, would be to define your own specialized profile: you could then define the  stereotypes `«DockerContainer»` and `«VirtualMachine»` that would add the missing expressivity to nodes.